# Laravel trying to add custom css file inside a partial view with @include

Tags: laravel, partial-views

In my Laravel project I want to that some of my partial views (like the header and footer partial views) to have their own CSS file but I just can't seem to figue out how to achieve that.

I've read in the documentation that the best to achieve that is to use the `stack` and `push` directives, however it turned that that they don't work inside an `include` directive.

I've created an `app.blade.php` inside `resouces/views/layouts`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    
    <title>Tutorial</title>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url('assets/css/global.css') }}" />
    @yield('styles')
</head>
<body>
    @include('layouts.header')

    <main>
        hi
    </main>

    @include('layouts.footer')
</body>

</html>
```

I also have `header.blade.php`:

```
@section('styles')
    <link href="{{ asset('assets/css/common.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
@endsection

<header class="header">
    <nav class="header-nav">
        <ul class="pages">
            <li>
                <a href="/">Tutorial</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        
        <ul class="auth">
            <li>
                <a href="/login">Login</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/register">Register</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

and a `footer.blade.php`:

```
@section('styles')
    <link href="{{ asset('/assets/css/common.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
@endsection

<footer class="footer">
    <nav class="footer-nav">
        <ul class="pages">
            <li>
                <a href="/">Tutorial</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</footer>
```

But the styles just don't get imported and I can't understand what I did wrong!

Comment: err, i think you have a wrong idea about how `@yield` works, double check [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/blade#extending-a-layout). `@yield` is used to emit `@section` of an extending blade template.

Comment: @BagusTesa so how could i add a custom css file for a partial view used in ```@include``` ?

Comment: unfortunately, you cant. the `@include` directive very similar to php `include()` but has more flairs (conditionals, data passing, etc).

Comment: ps. if you need asset bundling to add css dynamically for each component (e.g. header, footer, etc) you should rely on something like Mix in older laravel or Vite for newer ones. but they might be too complicated for a "first time" project, it is easier to just stick the css manually on `<head>`.